# Making A Queue with LinkedList in C

Tags: c

So I was going through a textbook example of how to make a queue from a linked list in C and I'm kinda of stuck on how exactly a piece of codes works.

So the example the textbook uses is a queue that helps models passengers waiting in line to be served by a ticket agent.

They start off by defining the structure of how the queue will be implemented:

```
    /*  Insert typedef for queue_element_t */

typedef struct queue_node_s {
      queue_element_t      element;
      struct queue_node_s *restp;
} queue_node_t;

typedef struct {
      queue_node_t *frontp,
                   *rearp;
      int           size;
} queue_t;
```

Then they go on to show the implementation of two functions:

```
void add_to_q(queue_t *qp, queue_element_t ele);
queue_element_t remove_from_q(queue_t *qp);
```

The first function is defined as:

```
/*
 *  Adds ele at the end of queue accessed through qp
 *  Pre:  queue is not empty
 */
void
add_to_q(queue_t         *qp,  /* input/output - queue   */
         queue_element_t  ele) /* input - element to add */
{
      if (qp->size == 0) {                /* adds to empty queue    */
            qp->rearp = (queue_node_t *)malloc(sizeof (queue_node_t));
            qp->frontp = qp->rearp;
      } else {                            /* adds to non-empty queue    */
            qp->rearp->restp = 
                  (queue_node_t *)malloc(sizeof (queue_node_t));
            qp->rearp = qp->rearp->restp;
      }
      qp->rearp->element = ele;           /* defines newly added node   */
      qp->rearp->restp = NULL;
      ++(qp->size);
}
```

Similarly remove_from_q is implemented in the following way:

```
    /*
 *  Removes and frees first node of queue, returning value stored there.
 *  Pre:  queue is not empty
 */
queue_element_t
remove_from_q(queue_t *qp) /* input/output - queue */
{
      queue_node_t    *to_freep;    /* pointer to node removed  */
      queue_element_t  ans;         /* initial queue value which is to  
be returned     */

      to_freep = qp->frontp;        /* saves pointer to node being 
deleted */
      ans = to_freep->element;          /* retrieves value to return    */
      qp->frontp = to_freep->restp; /* deletes first node   */
      free(to_freep);               /* deallocates space    */
      --(qp->size);

      if (qp->size == 0)            /* queue's ONLY node was deleted    */
            qp->rearp = NULL;

      return (ans);
}
```

When I go through it by myself, I find that I am still somewhat confused as to why it works this way? Correct me if I'm wrong here: On the first call to the function add_to_q, we assume that the queue is initially empty so the queue_node_t pointers frontp and rearp both point to the same spot in memory allocated in heap. Thus as a result, frontp->restp == rearp->restp, which is why you are allowed to write the line 
                 `qp->frontp = to_freep->restp;` 
in remove_from_q? Plus, on the second call to add_to_q, when you add a second element frontp points to the same memory locate but rear moves to a new location?

My follow up to that would be that once one element is in the queue, if we go and add a new member to the back of the queue, how does the following block of code give us the correct functionality that we expect of our queue?:

```
else {                            /* adds to non-empty queue    */
            qp->rearp->restp = 
                  (queue_node_t *)malloc(sizeof (queue_node_t));
            qp->rearp = qp->rearp->restp;
      }
      qp->rearp->element = ele;           /* defines newly added node   */
      qp->rearp->restp = NULL;
      ++(qp->size);
}
```

I've tried drawing this out in terms of memory blocks, but I don't see how once the program gets to the line `qp->rearp = qp->rearp->restp;`, when you write `qp->rearp->restp = NULL;` it doesn't also set qp->rearp equal to NULL as well since they should (to my knowledge) be pointing to the same spot in memory.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thanks :)

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger, and watch what happens to all the values when you add/remove items.

Comment: `qp` must be a valid pointer to sufficiently allocated type `queue_t` and not `NULL` (without a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we have no way to tell). On first add `qp->frontp` is assigned the address of `qp->rearp` and `->element` is assigned `ele` and `->restp` set to `NULL`. (basically with 1 element `frontp` points to `rearp`) As elements are added each new node `qp->rearp->restp` is allocated and the address assigned to `qp->rearp` adding nodes to the list. Including a MCVE will help us help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A queue is a first in first out structure (I guess you already know that). This particular code implements it using a linked list. What it basically does is whenever you "enqueue" some data you add it at the rear end of the linked list (the tail). Thus, `rear` gets modified on every call of `add_to_q`.

> My follow up to that would be that once one element is in the queue, if we go and add a new member to the back of the queue, how does the following block of code give us the correct functionality that we expect of our queue?:

`qp->rearp` points to the last node (the rear of the code). `qp->rearp->restp` is the so called "next" pointer of that node. `qp->rearp->restp=malloc...` makes a new node at the "next" of the old rear. `qp->rearp=qp->rearp->restp` makes `qp->rearp` point to the new rear. `qp->rearp->restp` makes the "next" of the last node `NULL`.

---

So the code basically adds new nodes at the tail end of the linked list and removes nodes from the head end (the other way around should be more efficient). They are using the word "rearp" because you are supposed to go stand at the "rear" of a queue.

---

This is basically dealing with a linked list while keeping a "tail" pointer as well as a "head" pointer for efficiency purposes.

Comment: Aaah. I think I see. So basically, I could imagine that as the program executes the line `qp->rearp->restp=malloc...,` a new memory cell is placed "behind" the first element in the queue (i.e a person new to the line stands behind those already waiting), and then the line `qp->rearp=qp->rearp->restp` moves qp->rearp to that new spot in memory (i.e the newest person to the line)?

Comment: Why do you think that putting new nodes at the front of the queue would be more efficient ('the other way round would be more efficient')?  In particular, how would you remove a node from the tail of the queue and update the tail to point to the previous node, given that you have a singly-linked list?

Answer (score 2):

let's have some brief overview :

*Queue is  a **linear data structure**, in which the first element is inserted from one end called **REAR**, and the deletion of exisiting element takes place from the other end called as **FRONT**.*

**KeyPoint:** The process to add an element into queue is called Enqueue(insertion) and the process of removal of an element from queue is called Dequeue(deletion).

Now, I've created two design to let you understand the basic concept of insertion and deletion.

**1. Insertion( also creation)**

[image]

**2. Deletion in Queue :**

[image]

I hope you will understand the basic concept of queue using linked-list so that, you do not confused in future and can learn further.

Comment: Please see these two pictures carefully with Zoom in...I dont think there is any other easy way than  this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest drawing it out again (and again), with blocks and pointers. First, make sure you understand a simple linked list that uses only a head and next pointers.  Then progress to this one that maintains the head, tail and size info.  Your comments actually sound like you mostly got it, right down until your last comment about setting the last elements next pointer to NULL. (Hint: qp->rearp is now our last node, we put the element in it, and set it's 'next' pointer to NULL)

Comment: Ah. I think I'm starting to see where I'm getting confused. I'll trying drawing it out and posting a pic once I'm done. Thanks :)